# Not able to get the response code in react js axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

Here is my common method for post:

```
export const post = (url: string, param: any) => {
   const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken; // axios cancel request
   const source = CancelToken.source();
   post.prototype.source = source;
   return axios.post(url, qs.stringify(param), { cancelToken: 
   source.token }).then((resp) => resp);
};
```

Here is my post method:

```
const postMyMethod = async () => {
    await postMd(params)
    .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response) // in response not getting status code
    })
};
```

Below is the error handling code, how to get the response status code(ex: 200, 400...):

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  function (response) {
    if (response && response.data && response.data.Code && response.data.Message) {
      message.error(response.data.Message);
      response.data = null;
    }
    return response;
  },
  function (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.Code && error.response.data.Message) {
      message.error(error.response.data.Message);
    } else {
      message.error('Unknown error, please check your network ~');
    }
    return error;
  }
);
```

Finally if I do:

```
console.log(response)
```

Getting: `Error: Request failed with status code 400`

How to get the status code to do the if condition in the postMyMethod()?

I want to do like this in the postMyMethod(). How to achieve this?

```
if(response.status === 200){
// do something
}
if (respone.status === 400){
// do something
}
```

Comment: What's `postMd` ?

Comment: @slideshowp2 through that i m calling the common funtion

Comment: Any reason to mix `await` and then? use one of that not both together.

Comment: `axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.config);
  });`

Comment: only i m getting some for response.config, for other console reponse.data,status,statusText,headers getting undefined

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you are not using a `catch()` block in your `postMyMethod` function. You should add it so it will handle any error response. It will look something like this:

```
const postMyMethod = async () => {
    await postMd(params)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.response.statuscode);
  });
};
```

If response code 400 is something specific you want to handle differently in your function, your `catch()` block will be:

```
const postMyMethod = async () => {
    await postMd(params)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((err) => {
               if (err.response.statuscode == 400) {
                   console.log(err);
               } else {
                 console.log("something else");
               }
            });
        };
```

You can read more about the `catch()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it:

```
.then((response: any) => {
    console.log(response.response.status);
    console.log(response.response.data);
})
```

or need to add below code under function error > if condition

```
return error.response;
```

Now getting the response status and failure data.